# failed to boot android with a .rcS script by gem5

Tags: android, gem5

In my gem5 project, I have to boot android with a .rcS script rather than inputting the command, m5 checkpoint, in the corresponding m5 listening port. I can creat a checkpoint in Android in the second way, but I failed to do it in the first way. Moreover, I can boot Linux with a .rcS script by gem5. Although the gem5 process has run for an enough long time, any checkpoint was not created.
Please help me. Thanks for any help in advance.

My command line is as follow:

```
command line: /home/boyang/gem5-master.fwj/gem5-master/build/ARM/gem5.opt --
outdir=/home/boyang/gem5-master.fwj/gem5-
master/test.android/scriptdir.1cpu.Android.2 /home/boyang/gem5-
master.fwj/gem5-master/configs/example/fs.py --kernel=/home/boyang/gem5-
master.fwj/gem5-master/binaries/vmlinux-gem5-android --disk-
image=/home/boyang/gem5-master.fwj/gem5-master/disks/ARMv7a-ICS-
Android.SMP.Asimbench-v3.img --script=/home/boyang/gem5-master.fwj/gem5-
master/configs/boot/arm_ckpt_asim.rcS --num-cpus=1 --cpu-type=AtomicSimpleCPU 
--machine-type=VExpress_EMM --frame-capture --os-type=android-ics --enable-
context-switch-stats-dump
```

Comment: Does boot fail, or boot works and just does not checkpoint? I would recommend the following: understand how Android calls boot scripts, and determine which boot script is use to call what you pass to `--script`. Keep in mind that `--script` is just a setup for `m5 readfile` / `m5 execfile`: https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/1b0c52784874fa982a4ced5eab137359f34a8b84#m5-readfile so the likely candidate is `hack_back_ckpt.rcS`. Then add new prints / check existing prints to determine which script is not being called.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! My labmate secceeded to create a checkpoint by script in his computer while I failed. So I guess that I miss some dependencies. However, I do not have found them so far. Could you give some suggestions? Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: I don't know much about Android yet unfortunately. I will try to improve the state of the images at some point when I get some time hopefully however.